# Classic ADO.NET - is anyone still using it?

Tags: .net, ado.net

I use the ADO.Net SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataReader for all of my database interaction within my DAL. When I do a SELECT statement I cycle through my reader in a while loop and store each row in custom objects I have created.

It seems to me like nobody uses this method anymore, I hear all these things about LINQ to SQL and the Entity Framework. Is my method still an acceptable way of database manipulation?

Comment: All the fancy ORM use DataReaders under the hood. But this question is way to broad/off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - occasionally. For BULK operations, or when you really need to have total control over your SQL, or when using a full-blown ORM is just overkill (little apps, demos, etc.) - I still crank our `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataReader` objects at times.

Also - with Micro ORM's like [Dapper-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) and Massive (by Rob Conery), using "straight" ADO.NET and SQL statements might make something of a comeback, too!

Comment: Also, if you're just shuffling data between application and stored procedures you don't need more fancy stuff. Schema mapping for stored procedures compared to tables is bit difficult as the schema may change depending on what you put in (parameters). But I've seen my fair share of apps written completely in embedded/dynamic SQL and it's not really they way we want do things but there are a lot people out there who don't know of any other way.